# How to get to the key name of a referenced entity property from an entity instance without a datastore read in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Consider I have the following models -

```
class Team(db.Model): # say I have just 5 teams
  name = db.StringProperty()

class Player(db.Model): # say I have thousands of players
  name = db.StringProperty()
  team = db.ReferenceProperty(Team, collection_name="player_set")
```

1. Key name for each Team entity = 'team_' , and for each Player entity = 'player_'
2. By some prior arrangement I have a Team entity's (key_name, name) mapping available to me. For example (team_01, United States Of America), (team_02, Russia) etc
3. I have to show all the players and their teams on a page. One way of doing this would be -

   ```
   players = Player.all().fetch(1000) # This is 1 DB read
   for player in players: # This will iterate 1000 times
     self.response.out.write(player.name) # This is obviously not a DB read
     self.response.out.write(player.team.name) #This is a total of 1x1000 = 1000 DB reads
   ```
4. That is a 1001 DB reads for a silly thing.
5. The interesting part is that when I do a db.to_dict() on players, it shows that for every player in that list there is 'name' of the player and there is the 'key_name' of the team available too.
6. So how can I do the below ??

   ```
   players = Player.all().fetch(1000) # This is 1 DB read
   for player in players: # This will iterate 1000 times
     self.response.out.write(player.name) # This is obviously not a DB read
     self.response.out.write(team_list[player.<SOME WAY OF GETTING TEAM KEY NAME>]) # Here 'team_list' already has (key_name, name) for all 5 teams
   ```

I have been struggling with this for a long time. Have read every available documentation.

I could just hug the person that can help me here :-)

Disclaimer: The above problem description is not a real scenario. It is a simplified arrangement that represents my problem exactly. I have run into it in a rater complex and big GAE appication.

Comment: You already mentioned that `.to_dict()` gives you a `key_name` of the team; why not use that for your "some way of getting the team name"?

Comment: `Player.all().fetch(1000)` will cost as many DB query operations as many entities it'll return

Comment: @Amber +1 I should have used the dict given the amount of time I have spent on this. But I thought there must be another way to get is directly from the `players` entity list.

Comment: @PeterKnego I specifically mentioned a DB read (or more right to say datastore read) and not number of query operations as Google counts `Player.all().fetch(1000)` as just 1 DB read. You can use this to check app stats - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: There's no need to include 'team_' or 'player_' in your key names - key names are only unique across an entity kind anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside your loop, `Player.team.get_value_for_datastore(player)` will return the team's Key object without fetching anything from datastore.

If you wanted to pre-fetch all of the teams for a set of players (pretend you had more than 5, so didn't want to fetch them all if you're not going to need them all), then [this blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine) explains a good technique.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your given situation the only way to lower DB cost is to cache `Team`. If you use the new NDB API this is already done for you under the hood.

Comment: Hmm. I tried reading about NDB API. But all the wordings in the documentation were just as in the usual Datastore section. So much so, that it appeared to have been copied and put there. Will give it another read sometime soon. For now, I am just using dict as suggested by @Amber.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Team that a lot of Players refer to by key, and you want to list some subset of Player properties when you display the Team, and you want to minimize database reads, then you're going to probably need to denormalize, and cache some subset of Player information in a serialized blob (or a chunk of Json) attached to the Team. Lazily recompute the blob on membership change (if membership changes less frequently than team views, this is a definite win). This kind of update is the perfect use case for a background task.

Comment: This sounds great! Would you be able to point me to what you consider the best documentation for GAE + caching. I am relatively new to the world. Also, in my case the team-player membership never changes :)

Comment: There's caching information spread over multiple docs and presentations. If you haven't seen the various Google I/O presentations, I'd start there. Then cull through the appengine blog.

Answer (score 0):

A [ReferenceProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty) stores a [Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass). You should be able to use the Key's [id_or_name](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id_or_name) method to get the key_name.

Comment: Could you show me the code to do this without the operation being counted against DB read? A: I tried but it does get counted towards a RPC call and a DB read.

Comment: Player.team.get_value_for_datastore(player).id_or_name()